# Decrypting salted AES file generated on command line with Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I would like to decrypt a text file within a ruby 2.1 script which was previously encrypted using OpenSSL's commandline tools:
`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in my_file`

As seen in the command, the file is AES-256-CBC encrypted, salted and base64 encoded.

The password is known, but not the IV nor the key, which are required to follow this code snippet, taken from the [ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Encrypting+and+decrypting+some+data):

```
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new 256, :CBC
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = key
decipher.iv = iv

plain = decipher.update(encrypted_text) + decipher.final
```

While trying to find an answer, I found the gem [AESCrypt](https://github.com/Gurpartap/aescrypt) gem which supposedly simplifies en- and decrypting, yet the currently released version is not compatible with ruby 2.1.
Looking at it's source code, I found that the key was [retrieved by digesting the password](https://github.com/Gurpartap/aescrypt/blob/master/lib/aescrypt.rb#L43), and the [IV is just left as `nil`](https://github.com/Gurpartap/aescrypt/blob/master/lib/aescrypt.rb#L39).

So I tried to get the following running:

```
encoded_and_encrypted_text = File.read my_file_path
encrypted_text = Base64.decode64 encoded_and_encrypted_text.to_s.strip

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new 256, :CBC
decipher.decrypt

decipher.key = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new(my_password).digest

plain_text = decipher.update(encrypted_text) + decipher.final
```

But this results in `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: bad decrypt`.

Do I need to somehow specifically handle that the file is salted? I have read in the [OpenSSL documentation for the `enc` function](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) that the IV, if not specified while encrypting the file, is generated from the password. Do I need to manually reconstruct the IV somehow?

Any advice would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Try and look for code that implements `EVP_BytesToKey`... OK, one is now supplied below, you don't have to look far I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenSSL uses a custom header and key derivation routine. [Security.SE has a good description of the header](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139/2043) and the [docs for `EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) describe the key derivation.

We can modify your code to use this weird and somewhat broken key derivation as follows:

```
encoded_and_encrypted_text = File.read my_file_path
encrypted_text = Base64.decode64 encoded_and_encrypted_text.to_s.strip

header = encrypted_text[0,8]
salt = encrypted_text[8,8]
payload = encrypted_text[16..-1]

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new 256, :CBC
decipher.decrypt

D_1 = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new(my_password + salt).digest
D_2 = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new(D_1 + my_password + salt).digest
D_3 = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new(D_2 + my_password + salt).digest

decipher.key = (D_1 + D_2)
decipher.iv = D_3

plain_text = decipher.update(payload) + decipher.final
```

Comment: That looks like `EVP_BytesToKey` to me all right. Salt header is there as well. :)

Comment: @owlstead Yep, it's exactly an unrolled version of the description in https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html